# Redirecting cmd Output to textBox

Tags: c#, redirect, cmd, output

I'm Re-Creating the "command prompt" into a Windows Form.
The application is not working properly; and i can't figure exactly why.

When the form Loads it is suposed to run the cmd.exe (Load the cmd info into "TextBox_Receive"), but it doesnt; and also after writing any command in the "textBox_send" (that sends input); it will only show input after pressing "Enter" key 2 or 3 times.

Any idea what i am missing here?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Global Variables:
    private static StringBuilder cmdOutput = null;
    Process p;
    StreamWriter SW;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        // TextBox1 Gets the Current Directory
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        // This checkBox activates / deactivates writing commands into the "textBox_Send"

        cmdOutput = new StringBuilder("");
        p = new Process();

        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

        p.Start();

        SW = p.StandardInput;

        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();            
    }

    private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
// I dont actually understand this part of the code; as this is a "copy" of a snippet i found somewhere. Although it fixed one of my issues to redirect.
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            cmdOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Send "Enter Key" - Send Command
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            SW.WriteLine(txtbox_send.Text);
            txtbox_receive.Text = cmdOutput.ToString();
            txtbox_send.Clear();
        }
    }

    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable / Disable Sending Commands
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
            txtbox_send.Enabled = true;
        else
            txtbox_send.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is the use of `OutputDataReceived`. In the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx):

> The event is enabled during asynchronous read operations on
>   StandardOutput. To start asynchronous read operations, you must
>   redirect the StandardOutput stream of a Process, add your event
>   handler to the OutputDataReceived event, and call BeginOutputReadLine.
>   Thereafter, the OutputDataReceived event signals each time the process
>   writes a line to the redirected StandardOutput stream, until the
>   process exits or calls CancelOutputRead.

See the example code on that page for more details.

However - I'm not sure you need to go that route. Have you tried just reading directly from the [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) stream?

Comment: Thanks! =) I've Re-made the Code and redirects perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You might also try capturing the error data.

To do this:

after your line

```
p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
```

enter this line

```
p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
```

It might also be a problem with `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about that.