# Console output to textbox

Tags: c#, string, multithreading, console

I have been trying to grab the console output from the following to

```
private void List_Adapter()
    {
        using (Process tshark = new Process())
        {
            tshark.StartInfo.FileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fileLocation"];
            tshark.StartInfo.Arguments = "-D";
            tshark.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            tshark.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            tshark.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

           tshark.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(TSharkOutputHandler);

            tshark.Start();

            tshark.BeginOutputReadLine();
            tshark.WaitForExit();
        }
    }

    void TSharkOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            tboxConsoleOutput.AppendText(e.Data);
        }));
    }
```

But the ui just freezes, no info is being displayed am I just approaching this incorrectly

I have found the following and tried with no luck

[No access different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795948/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)
[Object different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732709/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)
[Redirect Output to Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492145/c-sharp-redirecting-cmd-output-to-textbox)
[Output to Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387869/redirect-running-process-output-to-textbox)
[Process output to richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521475/how-can-i-redirect-process-output-console-to-richtextbox)

Comment: Your UI freezes because of this statement: `tshark.WaitForExit();` You are blocking the UI thread, while the process runs. In fact, depending on how much output the process makes, you may be eventually preventing the process from continuing, because you're deadlocked on the `Invoke()` method call. It's not possible to provide a good answer, because there's not enough context in your question. But it will involve not calling `WaitForExit()` (and not disposing the `Process` object until you're done with it).

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I am doing that:

First you implement the following class:

```
public class TextBoxConsole : TextWriter
{
    TextBox output = null; //Textbox used to show Console's output.

    /// <summary>
    /// Custom TextBox-Class used to print the Console output.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="_output">Textbox used to show Console's output.</param>
    public TextBoxConsole(TextBox _output)
    {
        output = _output;
        output.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
        output.WordWrap = true;
    }

    //<summary>
    //Appends text to the textbox and to the logfile
    //</summary>
    //<param name="value">Input-string which is appended to the textbox.</param>
    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        output.AppendText(value.ToString());//Append char to the textbox
    }


    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Now if you want all your Console Output to be written to a certain textbox you declare it as follows.

First create a textbox and name i.e. "tbConsole". Now you want to tell it what to do:

```
TextWriter writer = new TextBoxConsole(tbConsole);
Console.SetOut(writer);
```

From now on every time you write something like `Console.WriteLine("Foo");` it will be written to your textbox.
That's it. Note [this approach is not mine](http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/). Also depending on how much output your Console produces it might have poor performance because it writes the output `char` by `char`.

Comment: @ondrovic does it still freeze? Maybe it's a problem with your output?